# flexslider with caption at top of slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I am using flexslider with a caption on each slide.
This works, except I want the caption to be at the top of the slide, not the bottom.
The only way I can see to put the caption at the top is to position it absolutely, but when I do that, the width of the caption is too wide (thousands of pixels, instead of as wide as the parent element).

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="data/homeSlides/brennys.jpg">
      <p class="flex-caption">Brenny's Motorcycle Clinic &gt;</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="data/homeSlides/aledoFireStation.jpg">
      <p class="flex-caption">Aledo Fire Protection District &gt;</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="data/homeSlides/trueNorth.jpg">
      <p class="flex-caption">True North &gt;</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="data/homeSlides/operationThreshold.jpg">
      <p class="flex-caption">Operation Threshold &gt;</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="data/homeSlides/sadler.jpg">
      <p class="flex-caption">Sadler &gt;</p>
    </li>                       
  </ul>
</div>
```

the css:

```
.flex-caption {
    background:rgba(73, 92, 94, 1);
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:right;
    color:#ff5200;
    padding-right:20px;
    bottom:0;   
    width:98%;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19211jyq/1/)

how do I get the caption to display properly at the top of the slide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.flex-caption {
    background:rgba(73, 92, 94, 1);
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:right;
    color:#ff5200;
    padding-right:20px;
    top:0;   
    right:20%; /*Adjust this by yourself to make it look better*/
    width:98%;
    position:absolute;
}
ul.slides li{
  position:relative; /*You need this*/
}
#wrapper{
  width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need some adjustement, first you need to set li relative so it becomes the reference box for absolute childs. z-index will bring the text on top for sure:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });


});
```

```css
.flex-caption {
  background: rgba(73, 92, 94, 1);
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #ff5200;
  padding-right: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;/* added */
  width: 91%;;/* added */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;;/* added */
}
li {
  position: relative;;/* added */
}
#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="http://pointbuilders.nbson.com/data/homeSlides/brennys.jpg">
        <p class="flex-caption">Brenny's Motorcycle Clinic &gt;</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://pointbuilders.nbson.com/data/homeSlides/aledoFireStation.jpg">
        <p class="flex-caption">Aledo Fire Protection District &gt;</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://pointbuilders.nbson.com/data/homeSlides/trueNorth.jpg">
        <p class="flex-caption">True North &gt;</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://pointbuilders.nbson.com/data/homeSlides/operationThreshold.jpg">
        <p class="flex-caption">Operation Threshold &gt;</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://pointbuilders.nbson.com/data/homeSlides/sadler.jpg">
        <p class="flex-caption">Sadler &gt;</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```